# Horizontal / vertical navigation

Tags: jquery, animation, navigation

I recently came across this website: http://www.mccormackmorrison.com/
I love the navigation method (vertical / horizontal scrolling) with resizing the background image.

If i look at the source it is an one page solutions without scrolling events, just sliders i guess.

Is it difficult to make a similar script? I researched for possible solutions but without result. Hope someone can "teach" me how to solve this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mccormackmorrison website is using [jQuery.SerialScroll](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/serialScroll/). You can check the demo of it [here](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/).

Hope this what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when i look at the mccormackmorrison page it seems it only scroll one page at the time. For example if i hit the "work" button, then hit the right arrow, en than hit the down arrow, it shows the page exactly at the right position.

Comment: For that you can use `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()`, take a `div` with `absolute: position` and some `z-index` and assign these values, and it will take full screen. It's very easy :).

Comment: I will give it a try, i will come with an jsfiddle if i have more questions left. For now on thanks !

Comment: The scaling doesn't work that well. But apart from the scaling method i was more curious to the sliding between the different pages method.

Comment: Here is what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/YKtXn/3/. Looks good to me. Just click on the Red Rectangle.

Comment: It's giving me some error about cross domain access for javascript if I open in different browser. You can test in html file, add jQuery and scrollTo script to that. You can modify this and play around, I have just shown you the way. You can go for glory :)

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer accept it. Thanks. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: I appreciate your help tremendously, now i have to play with it. I love it how they move vertically between the main pages and horizontally trough the sub ​​pages.